# apt ignores virtual package provided equivs-created package

Tags: apt, dpkg, aptitude

I want to [install pdftk](https://askubuntu.com/a/1028983/69674) on my development machine where I have installed (multiple versions of) Java with [SDKMAN!](https://sdkman.io). In order to fulfill the dependency on `default-jre-headless` of `pdftk-java`, I [created](https://github.com/reitzig/sdkman-equivs) a simple file for `equivs-build`:

```
Section: misc
Priority: optional
Homepage: https://github.com/reitzig/sdkman-equivs
Standards-Version: 3.9.2

Package: sdkman-java-11-open
Maintainer: Raphael Reitzig <4246780+reitzig@users.noreply.github.com>
Provides: openjdk-11-jre-headless, openjdk-11-jdk-headless, openjdk-11-source, default-jdk-headless, default-jre-headless
Conflicts: openjdk-11-jre-headless, openjdk-11-jdk-headless, openjdk-11-source
Replaces: openjdk-11-jre-headless, openjdk-11-jdk-headless, openjdk-11-source
Architecture: all
Description: Dummy package for OpenJDK 11 installed with SDKMAN!
```

I then installed the package with

```
equivs-build java-11-open
sudo dpkg -i sdkman-java-11-open_1.0_all.deb
```

Seems to have worked:

```
$ aptitude show default-jre-headless
Package: default-jre-headless            
<snip>
Provided by: sdkman-java-11-open (1.0)
```

However, the dependency is still not met:

```
$ sudo aptitude update > /dev/null; sudo aptitude install pdftk
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  default-jre-headless{a} java-common{a} libapache-pom-java{a} libbcprov-java{a} libcommons-lang3-java{a} 
  libcommons-parent-java{a} pdftk pdftk-java{a}
```

Same with `apt-get`. This is on Ubuntu 18.04.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David Foerster’s `pdftk-java` package depends on `default-jre-headless (>= 7) | java7-runtime-headless`; to satisfy that, you need a package with a *versioned* “Provides” (for `default-jre-headless`), or a package providing `java7-runtime-headless`. (I think the versioned dependency on `default-jre-headless` is incorrect; the default JDK/JRE packages are concrete packages with an epoch, so they all match that, and they’re not supposed to be used to enforce minimal versions.)

You should change your `equivs` file to provide the same virtual packages as the packages you’re replacing (`openjdk-11-jre-headless` etc.), with at least:

```
Provides: java-runtime-headless, java10-runtime-headless, java11-runtime-headless, java2-runtime-headless, java5-runtime-headless, java6-runtime-headless, java7-runtime-headless, java8-runtime-headless, java9-runtime-headless, openjdk-11-jre-headless, openjdk-11-jdk-headless, openjdk-11-source, default-jdk-headless, default-jre-headless
```

(You probably don’t need to provide the concrete `openjdk-11-jre-headless` and `openjdk-11-jdk-headless` packages, but I’ve left them in for simplicity.)

Comment: I saw this long list of provided packages, which doesn't make a lot of sense to me: a Java 11 runtime does _not_ double as a Java 7 runtime! But it seems it has to be this way (for now). Thanks!

Comment: I agree on the dependency. `default-jre-headless` has version `2:1.10-...` in the repos; `>= 7` seems inconsistent. It should probably be `java7-runtime-headless | java8-runtime-headless | java9-runtime-headless | java10-runtime-headless | java11-runtime-headless`. At least, that seems to be the intent.

Comment: More to the point: since `openjdk-11-jre-headless` provides all the `java_0runtime-headless`, I thought providing the single, specific package would to the trick. Are provides not recursive?

Comment: No, provides aren’t transitive.

Comment: Ah, that was my misconception then!

Comment: To clarify this further, “Provides” is intended (at its core) [for virtual packages](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html#virtual-packages-provides), so there’s nothing to anchor transitive dependencies on.